# Docker compose on ecr: ERROR: No such service: --build-arg

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I try to pass arg into the docker build process in this command:

```
docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml build my-app --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=5.0.0
```

But I got error:

```
ERROR: No such service: --build-arg
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) docker-compose have `build-arg` parameter.

The yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    image: 3144.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-app:latest
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The services should be last in the command line.

```
$ docker-compose build --help
Usage: build [options] [--build-arg key=val...] [SERVICE...]
```

So:

```
$ docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml build --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=5.0.0 my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it was Visual Studio 2019 that was trying to publish and putting the build my-app before the 'build-arg' parameter.

All I had to do is to update VS 2019 to the latest version 16.11.0 that solved this error during the publish from the IDE.