# Run docker compose inside a bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines

I need to run docker-compose with `--exit-code-from` . My local docker-compose binary accepts this command line and works just fine.

```
+ docker-compose -f file1.yml -f file2.yml up zookeeper-secure kafka-secure schema-registry-secure app integration-tests --exit-code-from integration-tests
```

However, I need to run this in a bitbucket pipeline. To achieve that I installed docker-compose using pip installer

```
pip install docker-compose
```

Which gives me version 1.29.2

```
+ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

And this version probably does not honour --exit-code-from  and hence errors out

```
No such service: --exit-code-from
```

While looking into docker docs, i found compose is now available in docker cli itself (though not very clear from which version onwards), but my bitbucket pipeline does not recognise that too.

```
+ docker compose help
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

Here is the docker version output inside my bitbucket pipeline

```
+ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.15
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.9
 Git commit:        fd82621
 Built:             Thu May  5 13:10:20 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.15
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.9
  Git commit:       4433bf6
  Built:            Thu May  5 13:10:29 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.4
  GitCommit:        212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.1
  GitCommit:        v1.1.1-0-g52de29d7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Any help will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `--exit-code-from` option was introduced in April 2017, [v1.12.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1120), I think the docker-compose v1 CLI parser is being much more picky than the docker-compose v2 you probably have in your workstation.

Telling by the `No such service: --exit-code-from` error message, simply move the option after the `up` subcommand but before the service list begins:

```
docker-compose \
  -f file1.yml \
  -f file2.yml \
  up \
    --exit-code-from integration-tests \
    zookeeper-secure kafka-secure schema-registry-secure app integration-tests
```

Very much related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840305/11715259

---

Otherwise, this question is about "how to use docker-compose v2 in Bitbucket Pipelines", which is a totally different topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069569/11715259