# How to use docker compose V2 in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines

Traditionally, I had been issuing

```
pip install docker-compose
```

instructions in my pipelines scripts for steps needing it, usually for integration tests.

This was convenient because it operates flawlessly with the docker binary provided by Bitbucket's docker service, and benefits from the pip cache since I am already using python images for those steps. But I'd rather work with up-to-date software, so I am looking for mechanisms to install docker-compose V2.

Ideally, the solution should

- not install another docker binary, but reuse the one provided by Bitbucket's docker service
- not require a specific runtime (unlike V1 requiring python)
- benefit from some kind of cache to avoid downloading the compose plugin on every single pipeline.

Is anyone addressing this? What's your experience?

Comment: If there is something you are installing prerequisites  on every run, you should make your own Docker image to use for building.

Comment: That would force me to build and maintain docker images for the product of any utilities I need with all the versions of all the runtimes used in my organization! Sorry to disagree but I'd rather use pipeline caches and start all script with some setup instructions. That's the approach with many "tool-setup" github actions, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to get it working is to download the latest release from github, place it in ~/.docker/cli-plugins and cache this folder.

```
definitions:
  caches:
    docker-cliplugins: ~/.docker/cli-plugins
  yaml-anchors:
    - &setup-docker-compose-latest-script >-
        wget --no-verbose --no-clobber https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 --output-document ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
        || true
        ; chmod a+x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
        && ln --symbolic ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services: [docker]
        caches: [docker-cliplugins]
        script:
          - *setup-docker-compose-latest-script
          - docker compose version
```

This needs `wget --no-clobber` to benefit from the cache.

Ideally this could be done in a reusable way with a pipe, just like you would with "setup" github actions. But because pipes are only mounted the clone directory and not the whole agent, here you have this yaml anchor.

Comment: Thanks for your solution - it works just fine! Although, it's one year old. Have you found more "out-of-the-box" way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use atlassian/default-image:4, it already has docker compose V2 installed: https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/default-image/

```
image: atlassian/default-image:4
pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Unit Tests
            services:
              - docker
            caches:
              - docker
              - pip
            script:
              - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
              - source .env_example
              - docker-compose build
```

Comment: `atlassian/default-image` is a bloated mashup of unspecific runtimes I find unsuitable for any pipeline and I try to avoid it. The "the solution should not require a specific runtime" statement in my question is because my pipeline already requires a specific runtime I am not willing to change. E.g. if my pipeline requires `python:3.12.0b3` and docker-compose then Atlassian's default image is not useful.