# How to test Guzzle on bitbucket-pipeline?

Tags: php, bitbucket, guzzle, bitbucket-pipelines

I wrote some integration tests using Guzzle.
I also created a pipeline on bitbucket that run through the tests.

```
$this->client = new Client([
  'base_uri' => "http://{docker_service_name}/api/",
]);
$response = $this->client->request('GET', 'regions');

$this->assertEquals(SELF::STATUS_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
```

My bitbucket-pipeline.yaml look similar to this:

```
image: php:7.1.1
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

The problem is that the pipeline fails with this error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to docker_service_name port 80: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://{docker_service_name}/api/regions
```

Looks like the pipeline is not able to get the hostname, in my local it would be the name of the docker webserver, what should I set on the pipeline?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Where is it stored in your local environment?

Comment: Hi Randommm, thanks for answering me
do you mean the variable {docker_service_name}?
I was using pseudo-code for the example but, in my local environment, that represents the name of the Docker container that has the web server in it.
My problem is that, for my understanding, there is no web server on the bitbucket pipeline, and if there is, I don't know how to get its name (thus the hostname) to use in my guzzle request during the test.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that step scripts are executed in a single docker container. If you need to connect to some other services to run integration tests, you should either:

- Start the necessary containers as pipeline services, recommended if they are standard databases https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/
- Install and use docker-compose to start custom services and probably run the very tests inside a container as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069569/11715259
- Start the services in your very script but detaching from them, leaving them to run in background. Then simply connect to 127.0.0.1