# Can't run compose in Bitbucket pipeline getting --privileged=true is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-buildkit

I also opened an issue for this on the Atlassian community forum: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Work-Management-Questions/Can-t-run-compose-in-bitbucket-pipelines-getting-privileged-true/qaq-p/2233411

Bitbucket pipelines are supposed to support buildkit now and they even say in their docs compose is supported as well.

This is my compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  myservice:
    platform: linux/amd64
    privileged: false # I also tried adding this
    image: someimage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
      secrets:
        - pypi_conf

secrets:
  pypi_conf:
    file: "${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/pypi_config/pip/pip.conf"
```

This is my yaml:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
  steps:
    - step: &build
        name: Build
        image:
          name: tiangolo/docker-with-compose
        script:
          - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
          - docker compose build
        services:
          - docker
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *build
```

I'm not mounting anything outside of the allowed `BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR`.

But I get this error:

```
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 3.1s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_default done
#1 ERROR: Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: --privileged=true is not allowed
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: --privileged=true is not allowed
make: *** [Makefile:134: testing] Error 17
```

### Update

I found that both `docker-compose` and `docker compose` fail if I turn on buildkit with `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`. So it's not even just the secret mounting feature, it's Compose + buildkit that generates this error.

Comment: This might be related https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-17590?focusedCommentId=3118538#comment-3118538 . Essentially, some buildkit features trigger the "--privileged=true is not allowed" error despite that mode is unnecessary and explictly disabled. My gut would be that secrets feature you are using might be the trigger here? Or maybe that tiangolo/docker-with-compose could be shadowing some hacks from the bitbucket pipelines docker engine? I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069569/11715259 to get docker-compose V2, it might be of your interest.

Comment: The normal thing to do would be to report an issue at https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/BCLOUD/issues/ but ever since https://bitbucket.org/blog/were-listening-leveling-up-how-we-gather-review-and-respond-to-product-feedback this turned out to be unfeasible.

Comment: @N1ngu are you able to use compose v2 with secrets? I found both `docker-compose` and `docker compose` fail as soon as I turn on buildkit with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` so regardless of me using the feature or not compose + buildkit fails.

Comment: Nope, I never used secrets during builds yet. Have you tried the bare `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . --whatnot` equivalent instruction so as to test if buildkit can build that? Does your `tiangolo/docker-with-compose` runner feature a non-default builkit plugin in `~/.docker/cli-plugins`? (I had trouble with that)

Comment: buildkit works with regular docker commands and compose works without buildkit.

Comment: I think that the underlying issue is that you want i) use buildkit and ii) use a docker compose file. In order to do so you'd need the docker buildkit buildx builder which is the default builder for buildkit which in turn is not allowed by Atlassian.