# Use installed tooling from previous step in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to understand more about pipelines and I created this pipeline file. How can I reuse the awscli installation that occurs in the `&build-ecr` step in the `&update-ecs` step?

**ERROR**

```
+ aws ecs update-service --service $SERVICE_NAME --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME .
bash: aws: command not found
```

To make it work, I had to duplicate the AWSCLI installation in `- step: &update-ecs`. If the installation is removed, the above error occurs.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image:
  name: atlassian/default-image:4

definitions:
  caches:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
  steps:
    - step: &set-env-sprint
                      (...)

    - step: &set-env-prod
                      (...)

    - step: &build-ecr
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - source .env.global

          - echo "Build environment ${ENV_ECS}"

          - curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.13.3.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
          - unzip awscliv2.zip
          - ./aws/install

          - aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names $REPOSITORY || aws ecr create-repository --repository-name $REPOSITORY
          - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $IMAGE

          - docker build --build-arg ENV_APP=${ENV_APP} -t $IMAGE_URI ./
          - docker push $IMAGE_URI

    - step: &deploy-ecs
                      (...)

    - step: &update-ecs
        script:
          - source .env.global

          - curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.13.3.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
          - unzip awscliv2.zip
          - ./aws/install 

          - aws ecs update-service --service $SERVICE_NAME --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --load-balancers $LOAD_BALANCER_NAME

pipelines:
  branches:
    sprint:
      - step: *set-env-sprint
      - step: *build-ecr
      - step: *deploy-ecs
        script:
          - sleep 60
      - step: *update-ecs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By design, you can't**

Each step is executed in a new pristine docker container with a potentially different image from other steps, so most usually the installed software would be incompatible.

Any necessary tooling for a step must be either installed at the start of the step's script or shipped in the docker image.

You can use caches to speedup such installation **but you can't abuse the cache to skip the installation**. If you are using `apt` to install `aws-cli` you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959639/11715259. If you are using `yum` or `apk` or anything else you can develop similar approaches. If you are downloading binaries without a package manager, you can try to benefit from `wget --no-clobber` instead of `curl`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069569/11715259.

**You should avoid `image: atlassian/default-image:4`:** it is a bloated mashup of unspecific runtimes. Your use-case is actually resolved with `image: amazon/aws-cli` without further tooling setup.

TL;DR: just choose a docker image that already features the tooling you need.

Comment: I'm learning, some concepts are still being developed. The image: amazon/aws-cli worked perfectly. Thanks :)